# Centering tabular

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

Using `\centering` or the `table` environment doesn't seem to change the text inside the tabular. It shouldn't be a problem the graphics with tikz or the `microtype`.

How can they be centered without the left margin (using up all the page horizontal space) ?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{listingsutf8}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\setlist[itemize]{topsep=0pt,after=\newline}

\hyphenpenalty=10000
\exhyphenpenalty=10000

\newcommand{\tableau}[1]{{\sffamily #1}}
\newcommand\tab[1][0.75cm]{\hspace*{#1}}


\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\newcommand*{\DrawArrow}[3][]{%
% #1 = draw options
% #2 = left point
% #3 = right point
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw [thick, -stealth, #1] ($(#2)+(0.35em,-0.5ex)$) to ($(#3)+(0.25em,-0.5ex)$);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[
leftmargin=0pt,
itemindent=15pt,
listparindent=0.7cm,
labelwidth=15pt,
itemsep=10pt,
parsep=7.5pt,
]
\item {\sffamily acgaccccaa}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{4}{c}}
        \$ & a & c & g\\
        \{10\} & \{0,3,8,9\} & \{\tikzmark{1}1,4,5,6,7\} & \{\tikzmark{2}2\}            
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{2}{1}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{5}{c}}
        \$ & a & c & cg & g\\
        \{10\} & \{\tikzmark{0}0,3,8,9\} & \{4,5,6,7\} & \{\tikzmark{1}1\} & \underline{\{2\}}          
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{1}{0}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{6}{c}}
        \$ & a & acg & c & cg & g\\
        \{10\} & \{\tikzmark{3}3,8,9\} & \{0\} & \{\tikzmark{4}4,\tikzmark{5}5,\tikzmark{6}6,\tikzmark{7}7\} & \underline{\{1\}} & \underline{\{2\}}            
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{4}{3}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{5}{3}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{6}{3}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{7}{3}

\vspace{0.5cm}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{7}{c}}
        \$ & a & acccc & acg & c & cg & g\\
        \underline{\{10\}} & \underline{\{8,9\}} & \underline{\{3\}} & \underline{\{0\}} & \underline{\{4,5,6,7\}} & \underline{\{1\}} & \underline{\{2\}}          
    \end{tabular*}
}

\item {\sffamily aeeeaaeabceeedee}


\textls[120]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{6}{c}}
        \$ & a & b & c & d & e\\
        \{16\} & \{\tikzmark{0}0,4,\tikzmark{5}5,7\} & \{8\} & \{\tikzmark{9}9\} & \{\tikzmark{13}13\} & \{\tikzmark{1}1,\tikzmark{2}2,\tikzmark{3}3,\tikzmark{6}6,\tikzmark{10}10,\tikzmark{11}11,\tikzmark{12}12,\tikzmark{14}14,\tikzmark{15}15\}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{1}{0}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{2}{0}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{3}{0}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -18]{6}{5}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -39]{10}{9}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -39]{11}{9}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -39]{12}{9}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{14}{13}
\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{15}{13}

\vspace{1.5cm}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c}}
        \$ & a & ae & aeee & b & ceee & dee & e\\
        \{16\} & \{4,7\} & \{6\} & \{0\} & \{8\} & \{\tikzmark{9}9\} & \{\tikzmark{13}13\} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{13}{9}


\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c}}
        \$ & a & ae & aeee & b & ceeedee & dee & e\\
        \{16\} & \{4,7\} & \{6\} & \{0\} & \{\tikzmark{8}8\} & \{\tikzmark{9}9\} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{9}{8}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c}}
        \$ & a & ae & aeee & bceeedee & ceeedee & dee & e\\
        \{16\} & \{4,\tikzmark{7}7\} & \{6\} & \{0\} & \{\tikzmark{8}8\} & \underline{\{9\}} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{8}{7}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{8}{c}}
        \$ & abceeedee & ae & aeee & bceeedee & ceeedee & dee & e\\
        \{16\} & \{\tikzmark{4}4,7\} & \{\tikzmark{6}6\} & \underline{\{0\}} & \underline{\{8\}} & \underline{\{9\}} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
    \end{tabular*}  
}

\DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{6}{4}

\textls[80]{
    \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{9}{c}}
        \$ & abceeedee & abceeedeeae & ae & aeee & bceeedee & ceeedee & dee & e\\
        \underline{\{16\}} & \underline{\{7\}} & \underline{\{4\}} & \underline{\{6\}} & \underline{\{0\}} & \underline{\{8\}} & \underline{\{9\}} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
    \end{tabular*}
}

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Here are the result: I would like the tabular to be centered along the page.

> [image: Imgur]

What I would like to see is that each tabular align center with the page, without the left margin, a true center of all the table to the page.

The 2 to 3 last tables are wider than `\textwidth`, so they won't align well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: instead of `tabular*`, `tabular` is sufficient, and with `makebox` and the `center` environment, it does the centering I wanted.

```
\begin{center}

    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
        \textls[80]{
        \begin{tabular}{*{8}{c}}
            \$ & abceeedee & ae & aeee & bceeedee & ceeedee & dee & e\\
            \{16\} & \{\tikzmark{4}4,7\} & \{\tikzmark{6}6\} & \underline{\{0\}} & \underline{\{8\}} & \underline{\{9\}} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
        \end{tabular}   
        }
    }

   \DrawArrow[blue,out=-90, in=-90, bend right = -30]{6}{4}

    \makebox[\textwidth][c]{
        \textls[80]{%
            \begin{tabular}{*{9}{c}}
            \$ & abceeedee & abceeedeeae & ae & aeee & bceeedee & ceeedee & dee & e\\
            \underline{\{16\}} & \underline{\{7\}} & \underline{\{4\}} & \underline{\{6\}} & \underline{\{0\}} & \underline{\{8\}} & \underline{\{9\}} & \underline{\{13\}} & \underline{\{1,2,3,6,10,11,12,14,15\}}
        \end{tabular}%
        }
    }

\end{center}
```

[image: centering adjust]

Answer (score 2):

There are paragraph indents and unwanted spaces. Adding `\noindent` and commenting line ends helps. Also, `\linewidth` is the current line width that is set by other environments like `enumerate`, `quote`, ...

```
\noindent
\textls[80]{%
    \begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}*{4}{c}}
        \$ & a & c & g\\
        \{10\} & \{0,3,8,9\} & \{\tikzmark{1}1,4,5,6,7\} & \{\tikzmark{2}2\}
    \end{tabular*}%
}
```

The remaining overfull `\hbox` warnings are cases, where the width of the table is much too large. Switch to landscape or redesign the layout.

Comment: I'm thinking of redesigning the layout to make the margins bigger